# Which sqlAlchemy can be used to apply onupdate function and not to wait for session to be closed?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy, onupdate

Hi I've seen that onupdate function is not applied until the session is closed and I would like if there is any way to update db and use the onupdate function in the middle of a process.

I've tried with commit and flusk but no results...

```
created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now, index=True)
updated = Column(DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now, index=True)
```